# Representations of a semigroup over a Hilbert space

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, semigroups, semigroup-of-operators, noncommutative-geometry

A representations of a discrete semigroup $S$ with an involution $\star$ over a Hilbert space $H$ is a semigroup homomorphism $\varphi : S \to B(H)$ that preserve the involution. That is, for any $a, b\in S$

1. $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$
2. $\varphi(a^{\star})=\varphi(a)^{\star}$

There is a construction that represent any inverse semigroup over a Hilbert space which I found from [this paper,](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/7015D24EBE5981FFCE02CBD7FCBD89F7/S0013091500003187a.pdf/calgebras_of_inverse_semigroups.pdf) but do not understand some parts of it. Let me rephrase it here as I understood:

It start with the $\star$-group-algebra $\mathbb{C}[S]=\left\{\sum_{\text{finite}}az_a : a\in S, z_a\in\mathbb{C}\right\}$ whose objects are formal finite linear combinations and addition, scalar multiplication, product, $\star$ operations defined in most obvious ways. Then completion of $\mathbb{C}[S]$ under $l_2$ norm $\left\Vert \sum_{}az_a\right\Vert_2=\sqrt{\sum_{} |z_a|^2}$ makes it into a Hilbert space denoted by $l^2(S).$ So we have a chain of inclusions $S\hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}[S]\hookrightarrow l^2(S)$ and we have a representation $\varphi : S\to B(l^2(S))$ given by $$\varphi(a)(b) =
\begin{cases}
 ba,  & \text{if } aa^{\star}\ge b^{\star}b\\
 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and extended linearly and continuously. Now my questions are:

1. Is this the construction mentioned in the third page of this paper?
2. Is $l^2(S)$ same as the $C^{\ast}$-algebra mentioned in the first page as $C^{\ast}(S)$?
3. Where can I read about this construction with more details?

Comment: Could you be more precise regarding the place in the 3rd page the construction is mentioned?

Comment: @Ruy: It is first two paragraphs of 3rd page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Regarding your description of Duncan and Paterson's regular representation (which they call $\lambda $ and you are
   calling $\varphi $), I think you should define $\varphi (a)(b)=ab$, as opposed to $ba$, and
   require $a^*a\geq  bb^*$, rather than $aa^{*}\ge b^{*}b$.  Notice that with your definition you get an
   *anti-representation*,  that is, $\varphi $ reverses multiplication in the sense that  $\varphi (a_1a_2) = \varphi (a_2) \circ \varphi (a_1)$.
2. $l^2(S)$ is not a C*-algebra.  It is a Hilbert space.  $C^*(S)$ is the envelopping C$^*$-algebra of $l^1(S)$.
3. Paterson's book [1] has a lot more on C*-algebras of inverse semigroups.  You might also want to to check [2], where a
   different construction is made, and which is more suitable to certain important applications, such as the Cuntz-Krieger algebras.

[1] *Paterson, Alan L. T.*, Groupoids, inverse semigroups, and their operator algebras, Progress in Mathematics (Boston, Mass.). 170. Boston, MA: Birkhäuser. xvi, 274 p. (1999). [ZBL0913.22001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0913.22001).

[2] *Exel, Ruy*, [**Inverse semigroups and combinatorial (C^*)-algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00574-008-0080-7), Bull. Braz. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 39, No. 2, 191-313 (2008). [ZBL1173.46035](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1173.46035).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. So, do you think the way I understood this representation is correct? Also, what is the relationship between $l^2(S)$ and $C^*(S)$?

Comment: Yes, except for the detail I pointed out I think you nailed it.  There is not much relationship between $C^*(S)$ and
$\ell ^2(S)$,  except that $C^*(S)$ has a canonical representation on $\ell ^2(S)$.

Comment: Thank you again. I found the second chapter of Paterson's book [1] has more details about this. Also the condition I wrote $aa^{*}\ge b^{*}b$ comes as a consequence of interpreting them as partial bijections. So it says the domain of $b$ is a subset of codomain of $a.$

Comment: Only now did I realize you have $ba$ in place of $ab$.  Please se may latest edit.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out it. I didn't notice it until you mentioned. Also it seems like $C^*(S)$ construction is a certain adjunction (between category of $C^*$-algebras and category of inverse semigroups), because of the canonical representation.

Comment: I was reading the two sources mentioned in your answer over the last week. If you don't mind I have a very last question. What is the difference between the universal groupoid (Paterson, page 173) and the inductive groupoid (whose objects are idempotents and arrows are elements of the semigroup)? Here I don't warry about the topology or the order structure, but just wanted to understand whether these to constructions are isomorphic as groupoids or not.

Comment: The short answer is they are quite different, and used for different purposes.

It is my impression that the inductive groupoid  is more relevant to people studying structure theory of inverse
semigroups.

Comment: The universal groupoid,  IMHO, is more relevant to the study of symbolic dynamical systems.  For
example,  given an ample groupoid (e.g. coming from a discrete  group action on Cantor's set), the ample
inverse semigroup (formed by of all compact open bissections) can be used to recover the groupoid via the construction
of the tight groupoid (somewhat related to the universal groupoid).  However I believe the inductive groupoid has no
role in this situation.

Comment: Thank you so much. Initially I was studying something else, but gradually shifted in to this unknown territory of inverse semigroups, groupoids and operator algebras. I learned a lot from your answer and comments.